# Changed UTC time dumps after reboot in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, reboot, ntp, utc

I use Arch Linux OS with Linux 5.4.61-1-lts kernel, x86-64.

I noticed, that my UTC time is wrong:

```
[tao@dc ~]$ timedatectl
               Local time: Sun 2020-08-30 12:15:41 EEST 
           Universal time: Sun 2020-08-30 09:15:41 UTC  
                 RTC time: Sun 2020-08-30 09:15:41      
                Time zone: Europe/Chisinau (EEST, +0300)
System clock synchronized: no                           
              NTP service: inactive                     
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

while [here](https://time.is/UTC) I see 06:15:41.

I found only one way to change UTC time - using **ntp**:

```
[tao@dc ~]$ sudo ntpd -qg
[sudo] password for tao: 
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: ntpd 4.2.8p15@1.3728-o Wed Jul  1 17:02:17 UTC 2020 (1): Starting
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Command line: ntpd -qg
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: ----------------------------------------------------
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: ntp-4 is maintained by Network Time Foundation,
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Inc. (NTF), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: corporation.  Support and training for ntp-4 are
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: available at https://www.nwtime.org/support
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: ----------------------------------------------------
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: proto: precision = 0.232 usec (-22)
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: basedate set to 2020-06-19
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: gps base set to 2020-06-21 (week 2111)
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Listen normally on 3 wlp2s0 192.168.100.5:123
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Listen normally on 5 wlp2s0 [fe80::5aee:76d3:f600:ccc7%3]:123
30 Aug 12:20:15 ntpd[3371]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
30 Aug 09:20:21 ntpd[3371]: ntpd: time set -10800.518742 s
ntpd: time set -10800.518742s
[tao@dc ~]$
```

But problem is that after reboot this change dumps. I would like to change permanently UTC time.
I wouldn't like to put script somewhere in startup, I want to  sort out this problem.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

"Universal time" represents the system clock, which can be adjusted manually using various tools, such as `date --utc --set="hh:mm"` or `timedatectl set-time "hh:mm UTC"`. You're not required to use ntpd for this, although using NTP *is* much more accurate than doing it by hand.

But to preserve your changes, the system clock needs to be written to the RTC (battery-powered hardware clock) at some point.

If you keep the NTP daemon running, the RTC will automatically get updated every 11 minutes. (Always true with ntpd or systemd-timesyncd, but needs the 'rtctrim' option with chrony.) For portable systems I would recommend enabling `systemd-timesyncd.service` to handle clock sync.

If you do not want to run NTP permanently, then you'll need to run `hwclock --systohc` to save the system clock in RTC, every time the system clock is adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer, user1686. You gave me good hint.

I solved the problem. What I did:

```
$ sudo ntpd -qg
$ GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="clocksource=hpet"
$ su
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
# reboot
```

Hope, that this help for somebody. Thanks for help.

**UPD:** This solution doesn't works.